# Attention mechanism for RNN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, sentiment-analysis, attention-model

I m try to desing a rnn model to make a sentiment analyze.
So RNN to predict the sentiment (negative, neutral, positive, mixed) of giventext. The model iterates over the given word sequence using RNN and predicts the sentiment from the final hidden state. What would be the drawbacks of this architecture for the sentiment classification task and how would I improve this architecture using the attention mechanism?

For examples: 
”It is a very snowy day.  There are lots of traffic accidents.  At least children seem.  happy.”
”Yesterday turned out to be a terrible day.  I overslept my alarm clock, and to make matters worse, my dogate my homework.  At least my dog seems happy..."

Comment: [This article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.0473.pdf) is about the use of attention mechanism in RNN, so it may be helpful to you. But I wonder why you don't use [BERT](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.04805.pdf) - current SOTA on Natural Language Understanding for this task?

Comment: Thanks for the article. It is usefull. I have never tried bert before. what is the advantage of it?

Comment: also I read the article now and I could not understand that the architecture has attention mechanism or not. little confused. can you explain the architecture?

Comment: BERT is a Transformer-based architecture. The main advantage of Transformer over RNNs is the parallelism, so the computation time is reduced significantly. You can read more about Transformer [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf) or [here](http://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer/).

Comment: In article about the use of attention in RNN, you can see how this mechanism applied in section 3 (Learning to align and translate). In this paper, authors sometime use "align" instead of "attention".

Comment: I think [this article](https://jalammar.github.io/visualizing-neural-machine-translation-mechanics-of-seq2seq-models-with-attention/) may be helpful to you.

Comment: this is great article to understand seq-2-seq and attention. thank you!